# FFMPEG glue MPEG TS

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, video-encoding, video-editing

I have movie split in many parts with duration 10-30 seconds. All movies are MPEG TS files. I want to merge them.

I try to make following:

```
 ffmpeg -f concat -i join.txt OUTPUT.TS
```

and

`ffmpeg -i "concat:INPUT-1|INPUT-2" -c copy OUTPUT.TS`

both methods do the job, but resulting movie has issue if click somewhere forward or backward. Movie freeze, audio goes well and then it starts video.
I suppose I should restore or create some additional frames to make movie smooth.

What parameters should be passed to make result movie smooth with the same quality ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What parameters should be passed to make result movie smooth with the same quality ?

You probably need to regenerate the timestamps. Each clip has a separate timestamp stream, so when you concatenate them, the player perceives time as going backwards whenever it jumps from one part of the stream into a different one that was originally part of a different TS file.

Try adding `-fflags +genpts` in there, just before the output file name.

Incidentally, you want `-c copy` with the first command form as well. Otherwise, it may reencodes the files along the way.

Comment: Now, vide do not hangs up and almost smoothly. <br>but if I do not add -c copy, then all fine except video quality. How to reencode with same quality?

Comment: @Grous: That's a separate question, and it's a [duplicate besides](http://superuser.com/questions/525928/ffmpeg-keeping-quality-during-conversion). Use `ffprobe` to find out what your current video encoding parameters are, then use those same parameters or higher ones.